# How do I configure the XVLIDAR-ARDUINO MEGA?

Tags: arduino, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the line

```
rosrun xv_11_laser_driver neato_laser_publisher _port: = / dev / ttyUSB0
```

This message appears:

```
[ERROR] [1553391719.243142699]: Error instantiating laser object. Are you sure you have the correct port and baud rate? Error was open: Permission denied.
```

Please help me! :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319330/how-do-i-configure-the-xvlidar-arduino-mega-?/) by [Frank95000](https://answers.ros.org/users/40594/frank95000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-03-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-23**:
Are you sure that you have the correct port and baud rate? Also, do you have sufficient permissions?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-03-23**:
Make sure the user is in the dialout group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error means you don't have access to the port but implies the port is present.

Try this at terminal prompt:

```
sudo chmod a=rwx /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and try your node again to see if it works.

You can get more info on serial from the following(or at least 1,000,000 other links):
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-linux-serial-ports-with-setserial/

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2019-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0